# Insert a PNG into a PDF (as its own page)?

Tags: windows, pdf

Please suggest a tool to achieve this:

I am looking for a tool to solve *exactly* this (recurring) task:

- I have a multipage PDF.
- I have a PNG fitting well onto one page.
- I need a new PDF where that single PNG is inserted at a specific page index, as a new page. It should be scaled decently to fill the page, and the ratio should be correct; it doesn't need mm precision.
- Must be a quick operation (a few clicks) - faster than inserting the PNG in the original Word document, fiddling with alignment and exporting as PDF.

I need absolutely *no* other PDF-related feature; nothing at all. Neither now nor in the future. So a solution with a small footprint is preferred. Environment is Windows 10.

I'm technically adept, so if it is a command-line solution which can be scripted, that would be acceptable (maybe even preferred...).

Comment: Is writing code an option? Trivial to do with Java and `pdfbox` from the Apache group

Answer (score 1):

Self-answer: I found out that LibreOffice can open PDFs directly, move pages around, and also do some (limited?) text editing. It seems to fulfill my needs pretty much completely; except for the footprint.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go for PDFelement that works for both Mac and Windows.

And if you are looking for advanced PDF editor then you must try Nitro Productivity suite that works for Windows only.

Comment: Adding links would make this answer more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

1. convert image to pdf using `convert` utility from [inkscape](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Inkscape)
2. split and merge pdf files with the [`pdftk`](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Pdftk) command line utility